# Printing multiple arrays in descending order simultaneously

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to get my code to display the names and scores (provided by the user) in order from highest to lowest. My code also displays the highest grade, lowest grade, and average grade.

But I have no idea how to display the names and scores in order.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinalGrades {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> bestStudentPosition  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> worstStudentPosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many students are in your class? ");
        int totalStudents = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        String[] names = new String[totalStudents];
        double[] scores = new double[totalStudents];
        double maxGrade = 0;
        double minGrade = 0;
        double avg = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++) {
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            names[i] = input.next();
            System.out.print("Score: ");
            scores[i] = input.nextDouble();
            sum += scores[i];
            if (i == 0) {
                minGrade = scores[0];
            }
            if (scores[i] > maxGrade) {
                bestStudentPosition.clear();
                maxGrade = scores[i];
                bestStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i));
            } else if (scores[i] == maxGrade) {
                bestStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i));
            }
            if (i > 0 && scores[i] < minGrade) {
                worstStudentPosition.clear();
                minGrade = scores[i];
                worstStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i));
            } else if (scores[i] == minGrade) {
                worstStudentPosition.add(new Integer(i));
            }

        }

        avg = sum / totalStudents;
        System.out.print("Highest score: ");
        for (Integer position : bestStudentPosition) {
            System.out.println(maxGrade + ", " + names[position]);
        }
        System.out.print("Lowest score: ");
        for (Integer position : worstStudentPosition) {
            System.out.println(minGrade + ", " + names[position]);
        }

        System.out.printf("Average: %3.2f", avg);

    }

}
```

After the code is finished it should look like this. I have everything in the parenthesis:

```
How many students are in your class? 3
Name: Jake
Score 86.7
Name: Bill
Score: 91.6
Name: Alice
Score: 78.4


(Highest Score: 91.6, Bill
Lowest Score: 78.4, Alice
Average: 85.57)
1. Bill 91.6
2. Jake 86.7
3. Alice 78.4
```

Comment: What is the output right now?

Comment: Why use multiple arrays instead of having a `Student` class? Then you can use various sorting strategies to get the desired results.

Comment: I have everything in the ().